# What is Backwards Compatibility in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, backwards-compatibility

I'm a newbie to Android Development. Even though I referred the android developer [website](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html), I didn't figure out.

On the customize Activity dialog box, when I unchecked the `Backwards Compatiblity(Appcompat)` in Android Studio 2.3.1 It gave me a hint as:

> *If false, this activity base class will be Activity instead of AppCompatActivity*

[image]

Generally, what do android developers prefer? enabling backwards compatibility or without it? Can anyone explain me which one is better.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963902/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989121/115145 for some more background. There is no "better" in the abstract -- you need to define criteria against which one can compare options.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Android apps can be backward-compatible without checking this checkbox.

> If false, this activity base class will be Activity instead of AppCompatActivity

Android studio is letting you know that if you uncheck the "Backwards Compatability(Appcompat)" box, then you'll be including & using the library Activity instead of AppCompatActivity. 
For a more detailed comparison between the two, check this: [Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)

> Generally, what do android developers prefer? enabling backwards compatibility or without it?

A comment written by "CommonsWare" explains this best:

An activity created with that checkbox checked is no more backwards compatible than is one without that checkbox checked. Checking the checkbox gives your app a particular look and feel that will retain that look and feel on some older devices; leaving the checkbox unchecked means that some aspects of your look and feel will be different on pre-Android 5.0 devices. This does not impact the core functionality of the activity, though. – CommonsWare

Comment: Android apps can be backwards compatible without checking this checkbox.

Comment: That's true. But if you check the "Backwards Compatability(Appcompat)" box when creating a project, it builds the project in a way already suited for backward compatibility.

Comment: An activity created with that checkbox checked is no more backwards compatible than is one without that checkbox checked. Checking the checkbox gives your app a particular look and feel that will retain that look and feel on some older devices; leaving the checkbox unchecked means that some aspects of your look and feel will be different on pre-Android 5.0 devices. This does not impact the core functionality of the activity, though.

Comment: I just checked to make sure, and it seems you are completely right. When I originally studied it, I always thought that it doesn't change the core functionality like you mentioned, but it adds a lot of unnecessary libraries (If you don't care towards backward compatibility) and that is not the case. Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 8):

Backwards compatibility allows you to use certain backwards compatible features in your app. They will be able to work on previous versions of Android.

> The Android Support Library offers backward-compatible versions of a number of features that are not built into the framework. [(Android Support Library website)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)

For example, instead of `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity` will be used and is something that is "backwards" compatible. It can be used all the way back to API level 15.

Comment: Android apps can be backwards compatible without checking this checkbox.

Comment: Ah, I should clarify that. My bad.

Answer (score -2):

You should generally use `AppCompatActivity` to support older Android versions. If your app has no need for older android versions, then just use `Activity`.

Using `AppCompatActivity` is generally more recommended.

Comment: As mentioned above, this options affect only how your app looks, you can support older andro versions with "just" `Activity` too.