# Cannot create new Activity or new Project without Backward Compatibility

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5, android-studio-3.5.3

I am new to Android Development. I've been using the book "Head First Android Development". In it, it describes creating new projects and new activities, unchecking the "Backward Compatibility" option. However, my version of Android Studio does not have such an option to uncheck when creating new activities. Is there a way to disable Backward Compatibility when creating new activities in Android Studio? If not, can I manually alter the java source code to use `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`? What else would I need to change if I take this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created you're new Activity just rename:

```
class example extends AppCompatActivity(){}
```

to this:

```
class example extends Activity(){}
```

so you should just remove: AppCompat

But as you said you are a new android developer so i suggest you to use new educations.Also check this link maybe it can help you:
[What is Backwards Compatibility in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788103/what-is-backwards-compatibility-in-android-studio)